# Use a longtable in Lyx

Tags: lyx, longtable, kile, modules

The following compiles well in Kile but when imported into Lyx the title is duplicated and the "continued on next page" incorrectly appears at the end of the table.

```
%% LyX 1.6.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.


\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
\caption{A long table}
\endfirsthead
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Gene ID } & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Description}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next page}}
\tabularnewline
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Gene ID } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Description}\tabularnewline
\hline 
KIAA1539  & KIAA1539\tabularnewline
\hline 
TMEM98  & transmembrane protein 98\tabularnewline
\hline 
RHBDF1  & rhomboid 5 homolog 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
DCN  & decorin\tabularnewline
\hline 
HAGH  & hydroxyacylglutathione hydrolase\tabularnewline
\hline 
DGKA  & diacylglycerol kinase, alpha 80kDa\tabularnewline
\hline 
P4HA2  & prolyl 4-hydroxylase, alpha polypeptide II\tabularnewline
\hline 
GPR137B  & G protein-coupled receptor 137B\tabularnewline
\hline 
SLC22A17  & solute carrier family 22, member 17\tabularnewline
\hline 
TBC1D2  & TBC1 domain family, member 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
HSD3B7  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
TIMP3  & TIMP metallopeptidase inhibitor 3\tabularnewline
\hline 
ARSA  & arylsulfatase A\tabularnewline
\hline 
ENG  & endoglin\tabularnewline
\hline 
HPS1  & Hermansky-Pudlak syndrome 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
WSB1  & WD repeat and SOCS box-containing 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
H2AFJ  & H2A histone family, member J\tabularnewline
\hline 
PCTK3  & cyclin-dependent kinase 18\tabularnewline
\hline 
PLAGL1  & pleiomorphic adenoma gene-like 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
CPXM2  & carboxypeptidase X , member 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
XG  & Xg blood group\tabularnewline
\hline 
PSG2  & pregnancy specific beta-1-glycoprotein 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
TUBA1  & tubulin, alpha 4a\tabularnewline
\hline 
ISLR  & immunoglobulin superfamily containing leucine-rich repeat\tabularnewline
\hline 
CD68  & CD68 molecule\tabularnewline
\hline 
SLC44A2  & solute carrier family 44, member 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
DLG4  & discs, large homolog 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
REEP2  & receptor accessory protein 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
NES  & nestin\tabularnewline
\hline 
STARD13  & StAR-related lipid transfer domain containing 13\tabularnewline
\hline 
MYH11  & myosin, heavy chain 11, smooth muscle\tabularnewline
\hline 
NT5E  & 5'-nucleotidase, ecto\tabularnewline
\hline 
ITGA7  & integrin, alpha 7\tabularnewline
\hline 
ITM2B  & integral membrane protein 2B\tabularnewline
\hline 
NAAA  & N-acylethanolamine acid amidase\tabularnewline
\hline 
SLC16A3  & solute carrier family 16, member 3\tabularnewline
\hline 
IFITM3  & interferon induced transmembrane protein 3\tabularnewline
\hline 
CRABP2  & cellular retinoic acid binding protein 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
LHX9  & LIM homeobox 9\tabularnewline
\hline 
ECM1  & extracellular matrix protein 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
COL8A1  & collagen, type VIII, alpha 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
NMRAL1  & NmrA-like family domain containing 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
NCSTN  & nicastrin\tabularnewline
\hline 
PBXIP1  & pre-B-cell leukemia homeobox interacting protein 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
ESM1  & endothelial cell-specific molecule 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
CITED2  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
MAP1A  & microtubule-associated protein 1A\tabularnewline
\hline 
ANGPTL4  & angiopoietin-like 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
GDNF  & glial cell derived neurotrophic factor\tabularnewline
\hline 
IL7R  & interleukin 7 receptor\tabularnewline
\hline 
TMEM129  & transmembrane protein 129\tabularnewline
\hline 
GAA  & glucosidase, alpha; acid\tabularnewline
\hline 
MRGPRF  & MAS-related GPR, member F\tabularnewline
\hline 
SEZ6L2  & seizure related 6 homolog -like 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
IRX3  & iroquois homeobox 3\tabularnewline
\hline 
ADAMTSL1  & ADAMTS-like 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
C15ORF52  & Uncharacterized protein C15orf52\tabularnewline
\hline 
PDCD1LG2-001  & Programmed cell death 1 ligand 2 Precursor\tabularnewline
\hline 
HOXC6  & homeobox C6\tabularnewline
\hline 
PSG4  & pregnancy specific beta-1-glycoprotein 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
FER1L4  & fer-1-like 4\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I've even tried using a longtable module which didn't work for me:
http://www.oak-tree.us/stuff/LyX/longtablepage.module
Using this custom inset seemed to compile like a regular table, flowing past the end of the page rather than having proper pagebreaks inserted.

The one here: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#longtab-cap doesn't include the header at the top of every page or say continued on the next page at the bottom.

Can someone provided an example of a longtable that would compile in Lyx similar to the way my example compiles in Kile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, as is shown in the [LyX Wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#toc12), that longtables do not work inside floats, and there is no possibility to give a caption inside the table. But the hack given in the mentioned LyX Wiki section does not help as soon as you define a table head, because then the line with the caption in ERT is moved below the \endhead command. Thus, you have to define the first line with the caption command as a table head. The following worked for me (created with LyX 1.6.7 on Windows). I had to shorten the table, because the example would have been too long otherwise.

```
#LyX 1.6.7 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 345
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass scrartcl
\options DIV=calc
\use_default_options true
\language ngerman
\inputencoding auto
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a5paper
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\paperorientation portrait
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\defskip medskip
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\author "" 
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="35" columns="2">
<features islongtable="true">
<column alignment="left" valignment="top" width="0">
<column alignment="left" valignment="top" width="0">
<row endhead="true">
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
caption[short title]{A long table}
\backslash

\backslash
 %
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

%
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row endhead="true">
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Gene ID
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Description
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row endfoot="true">
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset space \hspace*{\fill}
\end_inset

Continued on next page
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row endlastfoot="true">
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
KIAA1539
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
KIAA1539
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
TMEM98
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
transmembrane protein 98
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
RHBDF1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
rhomboid 5 homolog 1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
DCN
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
decorin
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
HAGH
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
hydroxyacylglutathione hydrolase
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
DGKA
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
diacylglycerol kinase, alpha 80kDa
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
P4HA2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
prolyl 4-hydroxylase, alpha polypeptide II
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
GPR137B
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
G protein-coupled receptor 137B
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
SLC22A17
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
solute carrier family 22, member 17
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
TBC1D2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
TBC1 domain family, member 2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
HSD3B7
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
TIMP3
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
TIMP metallopeptidase inhibitor 3
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
ARSA
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
arylsulfatase A
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
ENG
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
endoglin
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
HPS1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
Hermansky-Pudlak syndrome 1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
WSB1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
WD repeat and SOCS box-containing 1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
H2AFJ
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
H2A histone family, member J
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
PCTK3
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
cyclin-dependent kinase 18
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
PLAGL1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
pleiomorphic adenoma gene-like 1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
CPXM2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
carboxypeptidase X , member 2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
XG
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
Xg blood group
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
PSG2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
pregnancy specific beta-1-glycoprotein 2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
TUBA1
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
tubulin, alpha 4a
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
ISLR
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
immunoglobulin superfamily containing leucine-rich
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
CD68
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
CD68 molecule
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
SLC44A2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
solute carrier family 44, member 2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
DLG4
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
discs, large homolog 4
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
REEP2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
receptor accessory protein 2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
NES
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
nestin
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
STARD13
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
StAR-related lipid transfer domain containing 13
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
MYH11
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\noun off
\color none
myosin, heavy chain 11, smooth muscle
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

This is too long for a comment, so I’ll put it in the answer:

I just realized that the caption is also shown on the second page, which it shouldn't. To change this, you can go to the table preferences in LyX and change the status in the longtable tab to “First head” instead of “Head” (the exact terms might be different, I use a German LyX). If you would like to have the caption also on subsequent pages, but with a different text, you can have two lines with the caption, one defined as “First head” and one as “Head”. For the continued caption, you have to insert a caption command with an empty optional argument, because otherwise there would be two entries in the list of tables. Thus, the ERT for the continued caption should look like this:

```
\caption[]{A long table (continued)}\\%
```

Comment: That's amazing.  Your files seems to work, and I spent a long time trying with no success.  I'm waiting a little bit to award the bounty just to do some more testing etc, but I think you've solved the problem.

Comment: Just curious, it labels the table "Tabelle" in the caption, how can get it to be english?

Comment: I think changing `\language ngerman` to `\language english` solves the problem

Comment: I'm going to reward the bounty for this answer regardless of whether you can answer this or not, but I have a follow-up question because I think you are skilled in this area.  Is there a way to format this such that I could export to LaTeX and import back to Lyx and still have it work?  While I prefer Lyx and would like my entire thesis to render in Lyx, some changes are quicker to make directly with LaTeX.  For example, I would like to use the headers of your tables with the data of mine.  This would be quicker to do in LaTeX than in Lyx.

Comment: Sorry one more question.  Is it possible to have the second and subsequent times the title caption shows up to make it say something like "Table 1.1: Cancer marked control overexpressed genes (continued)".

Comment: @denilw: I don’t think that it’s possible to export and import without loss. The import feature is not that powerful as one wishes, although I have to say that I don’t use it a lot and it’s some time since I tried it.

Comment: @denilw: Regarding your last question: I just edited the answer. See the bit under the LyX code.

Comment: I didn't know how to edit longtable preferences in LyX so that is very helpful.  I could find that information with a Google search.  I'm going to leave the bounty open to keep visibility of this answer and, correct me if I'm wrong, but the system should automatically award you the bounty at the end of the 7 days right?

Comment: I know I have a lot of follow up questions, I'm just excited to get this working.  I'm sorry but I have one more the caption "Table 1.8: Luminal marked luminal overexpressed genes
(cont.)" gets wrapped even though it's shorter than the textwidth.  Do you know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: @denilw: I don’t know what could be wrong with the long caption. I have no problems, only when the caption gets longer than the textwidth. Regarding the bounty: I have no clue, I never started one (c;